# python pywin32 after get a caputre with SaveBitmapFile I cannot delete the file

Tags: python, pywin32

```
#1.capture window
def window_capture(hwnd, filename, wmin, hmin, wmax, hmax):
    """
    :param hwnd: 要截图的窗口句柄
    :param filename: 保存的文件名
    :param wmin: 左
    :param hmin: 上
    :param wmax: 右
    :param hmax: 下
    :return: None
    """
    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    mfcDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
    BitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    height = hmax - hmin
    width = wmax - wmin
    BitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, width, height)
    saveDC.SelectObject(BitMap)
    saveDC.BitBlt((0, 0),(width,height),mfcDC,(0,0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
    BitMap.SaveBitmapFile(saveDC, filename)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(BitMap.GetHandle())
    saveDC.DeleteDC()
    mfcDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwndDC)

#2. capture window, user ocr to readtext
def ocr_capture(hwnd, wmin, hmin, wmax, hmax):
    TEMP_FILE_NAME = "tempCapture.png"
    window_capture(hwnd,TEMP_FILE_NAME, wmin, hmin, wmax, hmax)
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['ch_sim', 'en'])
    ocrRes = reader.readtext(TEMP_FILE_NAME)
    if (os.path.isfile(TEMP_FILE_NAME)):
        #---when I delete, there is an error say:the file is being used by anthor process-----
        os.remove(TEMP_FILE_NAME)
        print("remove tempfile successful")
    else:
        print("file not exist")
    return ocrRes
```

how I delete the file, or release the occupied file, becasue I need to looply capture window, I need to overwrite or delete the file.

the ocr_capture function capture the window by window_capture function, it will delete the img file after read the text from img. when I delete the img file, process get error say the file is being used by another process. how I fixed it. tks for any help.